# Stop motion claymation movie with various animals in it

Tags: identify-this-movie

My sister and I used to watch this movie when we were young.  It was in English. I'm 18 and I don't think I was younger than 7 or 8 years old when I saw it. I assume that it is from the 90s. We both remember that it was some sort of claymation with several different unrelated little stories within the movie. It was definitely a kids movie and the animation style was similar to that of "Fantastic mr. Fox"

One of the stories was about two rocks on a mountain and one of them wants to know whats on the other side of the mountain. He asks a bird to fly over and get a look then come back and tell him about the other side. The bird tells him that the other side of the mountain looks just like their side. The rock is satisfied. We remember another story that includes a wolf person trying to sleep while this cricket is singing. There is miscommunication between the two and while the wolf tells the cricket to quiet down, the cricket thinks she is telling him to be louder so he goes to get more crickets to sing with him.

I realize these are terrible descriptions but we can't remember a whole lot of the movie. It is a fairly unusual film, however, so I would hope that someone who has seen the movie would recognize the description. I have searched for it on the internet several times but can't seem to find it which makes me think that it is not a very well-known movie. I would appreciate any suggestions anyone may have as to what movie this is. Thanks!

Comment: I assume it's in English? Any idea about when it was made? You say you watched it when you were young, how old are you?

Comment: Yes, it was in English. I'm 18 and I don't think I was younger than 7 or 8 years old when I saw it. I assume that the it is from the 90s

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like the [1992 stop-motion adaptation](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0414287/combined) of Arnold Lobel's children book [Mouse Soup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse_Soup).

> In the second story, two large stones sit on a hill and wonder what's on the other side, as they can't move from the spot where they sit. When they ask a bird to check, the bird soon returns and tells them about buildings on the other side. A hundred years soon pass and when a mouse comes, the stones ask the mouse to check the other side of the hill. The mouse soon tells them that it is the same as the side the stones reside on. This make the stones feel glad that they're not missing anything, but wonder whether the mouse or the bird was right.
>
> In the third story, a cricket gets the urge to sing a song in the middle of the night, but his singing disturbs a lady mouse who is trying to get some sleep. Each time the lady mouse demands not to have any more music, the cricket thinks she said she wants more music and so calls over a lot of friends. Soon, the crickets are making so much noise with their singing that the lady mouse simply tells them to go away, which the cricket wonders why she didn't say so before. After the crickets go away, the mouse goes back to bed.

The movie is available in its entirety on Youtube. Here's the cricket story: